# Conectar Laravel ao MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

Estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação Laravel com Docker

Meu arquivo docker-compose.yml está assim:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.1
    container_name: mysql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "123"
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - code-network 
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links: 
      - mysql:db
    networks:
      - code-network 
  php7.3:
    image: quay.io/vesica/php73:latest
    container_name: php73
    volumes:
      - ./var/www/html:/var/www/html
      - ./etc/apache2/sites-available:/etc/apache2/sites-available
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    networks:
      - code-network   
volumes:
  mysql-db:  
networks:
  code-network:
    driver: bridge
```

A configuração do arquivo .env está assim:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=meubanco
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123
```

Mas quando tento acessar minha aplicação tenho a seguinte mensagem:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (2002) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `enable`
>   = S)

O que faltou ainda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri o problema:

Eu adicionei o link no container php73:

```
links: 
      - mysql:db
```

Então meu arquivo ficou assim:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.1
    container_name: mysql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "123"
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links: 
      - mysql:db

  php7.3:
    image: quay.io/vesica/php73:latest
    container_name: php73
    volumes:
      - ./var/www/html:/var/www/html
      - ./etc/apache2/sites-available:/etc/apache2/sites-available
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    links: 
      - mysql:db
volumes:
  mysql-db:
```

E no arquivo .env chameu o host `mysql`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=meubanco
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123
```

Espero que possa ajudar alguém futuramente

Comment: E o que seria o `db` em `mysql:db`?